# SAP GUI Scripting pop up message

Tags: vba, sap-gui

I am seeing this error pop up message which I do not know about it's `findbyId`, may I know how can I get its `findById`?

Also I'm using VBA to do scripting for SAP GUI, how can I catch the `findById` error and do some actions if I found it?

I know that there are `sbar` error messages but it is not the one that I'm having problem with.

Below is a picture of the pop up error message.[image]

Edit:

```
Sub Migo()

Dim i As Integer

If Not IsObject(Aplication) Then
    Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
    Set Aplication = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
End If
If Not IsObject(Connection) Then
    Set Connection = Aplication.Children(0)
End If
If Not IsObject(session) Then
    Set session = Connection.Children(0)
End If
If IsObject(WScript) Then
    WScript.ConnectionObject session, "on"
    WScript.ConnectionObject Aplication, "on"
End If

i = 0
j = 1
With session
    .findById("wnd[0]").maximize
    .findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "MIGO"
    .findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
    .findById("wnd[0]/usr/ssubSUB_MAIN_CARRIER:SAPLMIGO:0006/subSUB_HEADER:SAPLMIGO:0101/subSUB_HEADER:SAPLMIGO:0100/tabsTS_GOHEAD/tabpOK_GOHEAD_GENERAL/ssubSUB_TS_GOHEAD_GENERAL:SAPLMIGO:0112/txtGOHEAD-BKTXT").Text = Cells(1, 8)
    .findById("wnd[0]/usr/ssubSUB_MAIN_CARRIER:SAPLMIGO:0006/subSUB_ITEMLIST:SAPLMIGO:0200/tblSAPLMIGOTV_GOITEM/ctxtGOITEM-MAKTX[1,0]").Text = Cells(7, 2)
    .findById("wnd[0]/usr/ssubSUB_MAIN_CARRIER:SAPLMIGO:0006/subSUB_ITEMLIST:SAPLMIGO:0200/tblSAPLMIGOTV_GOITEM/txtGOITEM-ERFMG[4,0]").Text = Cells(7, 4)
    .findById("wnd[0]/usr/ssubSUB_MAIN_CARRIER:SAPLMIGO:0006/subSUB_ITEMLIST:SAPLMIGO:0200/tblSAPLMIGOTV_GOITEM/ctxtGOITEM-LGOBE[6,0]").Text = "BORD"
    .findById("wnd[0]/usr/ssubSUB_MAIN_CARRIER:SAPLMIGO:0006/subSUB_ITEMLIST:SAPLMIGO:0200/tblSAPLMIGOTV_GOITEM/ctxtGOITEM-NAME1[12,0]").Text = "2S98"
    .findById("wnd[0]/usr/ssubSUB_MAIN_CARRIER:SAPLMIGO:0006/subSUB_ITEMLIST:SAPLMIGO:0200/tblSAPLMIGOTV_GOITEM/ctxtGOITEM-UMLGOBE[27,0]").Text = "DMDV"
    .findById("wnd[0]/usr/ssubSUB_MAIN_CARRIER:SAPLMIGO:0006/subSUB_ITEMLIST:SAPLMIGO:0200/tblSAPLMIGOTV_GOITEM/ctxtGOITEM-UMBAR[32,0]").Text = "CATNEW"
    .findById("wnd[0]/usr/ssubSUB_MAIN_CARRIER:SAPLMIGO:0006/subSUB_ITEMLIST:SAPLMIGO:0200/tblSAPLMIGOTV_GOITEM/ctxtGOITEM-UMBAR[32,0]").SetFocus
    .findById("wnd[0]/usr/ssubSUB_MAIN_CARRIER:SAPLMIGO:0006/subSUB_ITEMLIST:SAPLMIGO:0200/tblSAPLMIGOTV_GOITEM/ctxtGOITEM-UMBAR[32,0]").caretPosition = 6
    .findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
    While Cells(8 + i, 1).Value <> ""
        .findById("wnd[0]/usr/ssubSUB_MAIN_CARRIER:SAPLMIGO:0006/subSUB_ITEMLIST:SAPLMIGO:0200/tblSAPLMIGOTV_GOITEM/ctxtGOITEM-MAKTX[1,1]").Text = Cells(8 + i, 2)
        .findById("wnd[0]/usr/ssubSUB_MAIN_CARRIER:SAPLMIGO:0006/subSUB_ITEMLIST:SAPLMIGO:0200/tblSAPLMIGOTV_GOITEM/txtGOITEM-ERFMG[4,1]").Text = Cells(8 + i, 4)
        .findById("wnd[0]/usr/ssubSUB_MAIN_CARRIER:SAPLMIGO:0006/subSUB_ITEMLIST:SAPLMIGO:0200/tblSAPLMIGOTV_GOITEM/ctxtGOITEM-LGOBE[6,1]").Text = "BORD"
        .findById("wnd[0]/usr/ssubSUB_MAIN_CARRIER:SAPLMIGO:0006/subSUB_ITEMLIST:SAPLMIGO:0200/tblSAPLMIGOTV_GOITEM/ctxtGOITEM-NAME1[12,1]").Text = "2S98"
        .findById("wnd[0]/usr/ssubSUB_MAIN_CARRIER:SAPLMIGO:0006/subSUB_ITEMLIST:SAPLMIGO:0200/tblSAPLMIGOTV_GOITEM/ctxtGOITEM-UMLGOBE[27,1]").Text = "DMDV"
        .findById("wnd[0]/usr/ssubSUB_MAIN_CARRIER:SAPLMIGO:0006/subSUB_ITEMLIST:SAPLMIGO:0200/tblSAPLMIGOTV_GOITEM/ctxtGOITEM-UMBAR[32,1]").Text = "CATNEW"
        .findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
        .findById("wnd[0]/usr/ssubSUB_MAIN_CARRIER:SAPLMIGO:0006/subSUB_ITEMLIST:SAPLMIGO:0200/tblSAPLMIGOTV_GOITEM").verticalScrollbar.Position = j
        .findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
        i = i + 1
        j = j + 1
    Wend
End With
End Sub
```

So the error happens inside the `while` loop sometimes

Comment: Have You tried just put your code or part where msg pop up in `On Error Resume Next` and `On Error GoTo 0` ?

Comment: It is more like this Error window does not open up most of the time, but if it does, is there any way to check for the existence of this window using `if else` by this code `session.findById("wnd[2]")`

Comment: I understand, but have You tried  `On Error` to avoid that if it pops up? I'm just asking from my VBA SAP experience. If You want to know the ID of this window You need to record macro in SAP and counting that this error appears :P

Comment: i do not know how to use `On Error`,i tried `On Error GoTo errHandler` and `Resume Next` but the code will run the next line instead of restart code and go on to the next row of information to input from excel. If u understand where im coming from.

Comment: Just put `On Error Resume Next` in the begining of your code and `On Error GoTo 0` in the end. If You wanna go back try 

`errhandler:
On Error Resume Next
On Error GoTo errhandler`

Comment: So i can put the `On Error` codes outside the loop?

Comment: I think yes, also it would be easier if You post your code :)

Comment: Can you answer the question with a code example so i can get a cleaer image of how it can be done? Thanks

Comment: Okay let me edit my post

Answer (score 0):

My main idea was:

```
Sub SAPcode()

errhandler:
    On Error Resume Next

    On Error GoTo errhandler

    'your code

    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

With your code probly it should looks like this:

```
Sub SAPcode()

Dim i As Integer

If Not IsObject(Aplication) Then
    Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
    Set Aplication = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
End If
If Not IsObject(Connection) Then
    Set Connection = Aplication.Children(0)
End If
If Not IsObject(session) Then
    Set session = Connection.Children(0)
End If
If IsObject(WScript) Then
    WScript.ConnectionObject session, "on"
    WScript.ConnectionObject Aplication, "on"
End If

i = 0
j = 1
With session
    .findById("wnd[0]").maximize
    .findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "MIGO"
    .findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
    .findById("wnd[0]/usr/ssubSUB_MAIN_CARRIER:SAPLMIGO:0006/subSUB_HEADER:SAPLMIGO:0101/subSUB_HEADER:SAPLMIGO:0100/tabsTS_GOHEAD/tabpOK_GOHEAD_GENERAL/ssubSUB_TS_GOHEAD_GENERAL:SAPLMIGO:0112/txtGOHEAD-BKTXT").Text = Cells(1, 8)
    .findById("wnd[0]/usr/ssubSUB_MAIN_CARRIER:SAPLMIGO:0006/subSUB_ITEMLIST:SAPLMIGO:0200/tblSAPLMIGOTV_GOITEM/ctxtGOITEM-MAKTX[1,0]").Text = Cells(7, 2)
    .findById("wnd[0]/usr/ssubSUB_MAIN_CARRIER:SAPLMIGO:0006/subSUB_ITEMLIST:SAPLMIGO:0200/tblSAPLMIGOTV_GOITEM/txtGOITEM-ERFMG[4,0]").Text = Cells(7, 4)
    .findById("wnd[0]/usr/ssubSUB_MAIN_CARRIER:SAPLMIGO:0006/subSUB_ITEMLIST:SAPLMIGO:0200/tblSAPLMIGOTV_GOITEM/ctxtGOITEM-LGOBE[6,0]").Text = "BORD"
    .findById("wnd[0]/usr/ssubSUB_MAIN_CARRIER:SAPLMIGO:0006/subSUB_ITEMLIST:SAPLMIGO:0200/tblSAPLMIGOTV_GOITEM/ctxtGOITEM-NAME1[12,0]").Text = "2S98"
    .findById("wnd[0]/usr/ssubSUB_MAIN_CARRIER:SAPLMIGO:0006/subSUB_ITEMLIST:SAPLMIGO:0200/tblSAPLMIGOTV_GOITEM/ctxtGOITEM-UMLGOBE[27,0]").Text = "DMDV"
    .findById("wnd[0]/usr/ssubSUB_MAIN_CARRIER:SAPLMIGO:0006/subSUB_ITEMLIST:SAPLMIGO:0200/tblSAPLMIGOTV_GOITEM/ctxtGOITEM-UMBAR[32,0]").Text = "CATNEW"
    .findById("wnd[0]/usr/ssubSUB_MAIN_CARRIER:SAPLMIGO:0006/subSUB_ITEMLIST:SAPLMIGO:0200/tblSAPLMIGOTV_GOITEM/ctxtGOITEM-UMBAR[32,0]").SetFocus
    .findById("wnd[0]/usr/ssubSUB_MAIN_CARRIER:SAPLMIGO:0006/subSUB_ITEMLIST:SAPLMIGO:0200/tblSAPLMIGOTV_GOITEM/ctxtGOITEM-UMBAR[32,0]").caretPosition = 6
    .findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0

    While Cells(8 + i, 1).Value <> ""
    errhandler:
        On Error Resume Next
        On Error GoTo errhandler  

.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ssubSUB_MAIN_CARRIER:SAPLMIGO:0006/subSUB_ITEMLIST:SAPLMIGO:0200/tblSAPLMIGOTV_GOITEM/ctxtGOITEM-MAKTX[1,1]").Text = Cells(8 + i, 2)
                        .findById("wnd[0]/usr/ssubSUB_MAIN_CARRIER:SAPLMIGO:0006/subSUB_ITEMLIST:SAPLMIGO:0200/tblSAPLMIGOTV_GOITEM/txtGOITEM-ERFMG[4,1]").Text = Cells(8 + i, 4)
                        .findById("wnd[0]/usr/ssubSUB_MAIN_CARRIER:SAPLMIGO:0006/subSUB_ITEMLIST:SAPLMIGO:0200/tblSAPLMIGOTV_GOITEM/ctxtGOITEM-LGOBE[6,1]").Text = "BORD"
                        .findById("wnd[0]/usr/ssubSUB_MAIN_CARRIER:SAPLMIGO:0006/subSUB_ITEMLIST:SAPLMIGO:0200/tblSAPLMIGOTV_GOITEM/ctxtGOITEM-NAME1[12,1]").Text = "2S98"
                        .findById("wnd[0]/usr/ssubSUB_MAIN_CARRIER:SAPLMIGO:0006/subSUB_ITEMLIST:SAPLMIGO:0200/tblSAPLMIGOTV_GOITEM/ctxtGOITEM-UMLGOBE[27,1]").Text = "DMDV"
                        .findById("wnd[0]/usr/ssubSUB_MAIN_CARRIER:SAPLMIGO:0006/subSUB_ITEMLIST:SAPLMIGO:0200/tblSAPLMIGOTV_GOITEM/ctxtGOITEM-UMBAR[32,1]").Text = "CATNEW"

                        .findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
                        .findById("wnd[0]/usr/ssubSUB_MAIN_CARRIER:SAPLMIGO:0006/subSUB_ITEMLIST:SAPLMIGO:0200/tblSAPLMIGOTV_GOITEM").verticalScrollbar.Position = j

                    .findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0

                    i = i + 1
                    j = j + 1
                    On Error GoTo 0
                Wend
            End With



        End Sub
```

Comment: @JiaHao Wang, have You checked anything?